# How to access repo directory in a Perl program in Openshift?

Tags: openshift

I hit the 404 error when I use the following the code in index.pl (I only create one perl app in my account)

```
my $hello_link = "$ENV{'OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'}hello.pl";

Click <a href="$hello_link"><font color="FF00CC">here</font></a> to run hello world cgi.</br>
```

When I log to my web autortl-rdlgen.rhcloud.com and click on ¨Here"to run hello program. The error message showed

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /var/lib/openshift/550f4df1fcf933b971000030/app-root/runtime/repo/hello.pl was not found on this server.

I do have uploaded `hello.pl` to my repo directory and can find it after SSH to my account:

```
[autortl-rdlgen.rhcloud.com repo]\> ls -tr hello.pl 
hello.pl
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a relative link like this "./hello.pl" instead of using the other link with the ENV variable, which is showing the complete filesystem path to your perl file.

You may want to check out some Perl tutorials to help you get started with your Perl web programming: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_cgi.htm

Comment: HI Corey, After replacing <a_href....> with <br/> the following: OPEN FILE,  "./hellp.pl" I still hit ".... Cant' open ./hello.pl: No such file or directory..." in $OPEN_LOG_DIR/perl.log. What's wrong with OPEN FILE command?